# How to Get Yandex suggested username using Googledriver selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to get the suggested username during Yandex email registration.

```
IWebElement element_firstname = driverTwo.FindElement(By.Id("firstname"));
            IWebElement element_lastname = driverTwo.FindElement(By.Id("lastname"));
IWebElement element_userlogin = driverTwo.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
element_firstname.SendKeys(fName);
            element_lastname.SendKeys(lName);
```

After this, usernames are suggested in login textbox from another window. Here how do I get the username using Selenium?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jmh0.png)

Comment: You can find an xpath/id/css selector of the popup text, make sure that it is visible, then grab the list of suggestions.  if you want to post the html, i can help show you

Comment: <div class="reg-field__popup"><div class="form__popup-error form__popup-text" data-t="login-error" role="alert"><div class="form__login-suggest"><strong class="suggest__status-text error-message">You must select a&nbsp;username</strong><div><div class="suggest__logins"><strong class="suggest__status-text" tabindex="4">Available usernames</strong><ul class="logins__list">